# Algorithm for check how much two rectangles intersect in the X axis

Tags: javascript, algorithm, intersection, shapes

I need an algorithm to calculate how much two 2D rectangles intersect if their Y positions are the same. I'm comparing several rectangles that might all intersect, and I'd like to pick the one that intersects the most, any help is appreciated

[image]

Comment: how do you represent the rectangles?

Comment: No worries I figured it out intersectionAmountX: function(a, b){ return Math.max(0, Math.min(a.right, b.right) - Math.max(a.left, b.left))}

Comment: @Aliza: Please post your solution as an answer. One major goal of StackOverflow is to have a collection of good questions and answers so that others who come later can find them more quickly.